# Yii, copying a dropdown value to hidden dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii

Basically, I want to know how can I copy an original dropdown value to the hidden dropdown.

Because currently I have a radiobutton that disables a certain dropdown value but the value will not be POST-ed in PHP. So I added in a hidden field with the **same name** of the original drop down but when it gets re-enabled, the field doesn't copy its value.

this is what I have:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'clientPackagedService_id'); ?>
    <?php $client = Client::model()->findByPk(1);?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'clientPackagedService_id', CHtml::listData($client->clientPackagedservices(array('condition'=>'client_id='.$client->id.' AND booking_id IS NULL')),'id','packagedServiceInfo')
        ,array(                 
            'disabled'=>'disabled', 
            'prompt'=>'Select Packaged Service....',
            'ajax' => array( 'type'=>'POST', //request type 
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('updateMasseuseAndStationListPSID'), //url to call.
                'data'=>array('clientPackagedService_id'=>'js:this.value', 'dt'=>'js:$("#Booking_date").val()', 'timeStart'=>'js:$("#Booking_timeStart").val()'),
                'dataType'=>'json', 
                'success'=>'js:function(data) {
                    var mass="#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'masseuse_id').'"; 
                    $(mass).html(data.masseuse); 
                    $(mass).trigger("chosen:updated"); 
                    $(mass+"_chzn").css("width","300px");
                    $(mass+"_chzn > .chzn-drop").css("width","298px");

                    var station="#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'station_id').'"; 
                    $(station).html(data.station); 
                    $(station).trigger("chosen:updated"); 
                    $(station+"_chzn").css("width","300px");
                    $(station+"_chzn > .chzn-drop").css("width","298px"); 

                    //alert(data.timeEnd);
                    var timeEnd="#'.CHtml::activeId($model, 'timeEnd').'";
                    $(timeEnd).val(data.timeEnd);
                }',                         
            ) 
        )
    ); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'clientPackagedService_id'); ?>
</div><!-- row -->

<div>
    <?php echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'clientPackagedService_id'); ?>
</div>
```

this is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
        if(this.value == '0'){
            $("#Booking_clientPackagedService_id").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#Booking_service_id").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#Booking_service_id").val('0');
            //I believe there's something I need to add in this line    
        }
        else if(this.value == '1'){             
            $("#Booking_service_id").prop("disabled", false); 
            $("#Booking_clientPackagedService_id").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#Booking_clientPackagedService_id").val('0');
        }
    });
})
```

Do I give the hiddenField the same name as my original drop down or should I not? If yes, then how can I copy the value of the original drop down into the hiddenField when it gets re-enabled?

Comment: Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Is the radio button necessary? How about add another value inside your dropdownlist, so inside your controller you can check using `if` block or so. `if ($_POST['Client']['clientPackagedService_id'] == '') {/*don't save the field*/}`

Comment: Yes, the radio button is a must. Otherwise it wouldn't have the meaning for it.

Comment: I don't get why, if disabling the value from the select, you still want to post the value itself to the server... if this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is because I have a function in my actionCreate() which requires the field, while disabling it will give me an error 500 undefined index. This is why I need it to at least post a null to the server.

Comment: Could you just check if the the value is sent *before* using your function? I mean, check if  "clientPackagedService_id" is in POST, if not add to the model like this: $model->clientPackagedService_id = '';, and then use your function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always check if the value is being posted, if so then do the function required. Else, leave it out. In my case I have a function that requires that value. So, I have added a check in my actionCreate();

This is my code:

```
if( isset($_POST['Booking']['clientPackagedService_id']) ){
        $model->bookService($_POST['Booking']['clientPackagedService_id']); 
        $transaction->commit();
}
else {
        $transaction->commit();
}
```

Thank you @Masiorama for his comment. I wouldn't have gotten it if he didn't commented.